# pip install pycurl Fails on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python, pip

I want to install `pycurl` using `pip` for Python 3.7 on Ubuntu 18.04. Python3.7 installed from "deadsnakes".

From `apt-cache depends python-pycurl` I get:

```
python-pycurl
  Depends: python
  Depends: python
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
  Depends: <python:any>
    python:i386
    python
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
  Suggests: libcurl4-gnutls-dev
  Suggests: python-pycurl-dbg
  Suggests: python-pycurl-doc
```

Then I installed the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl-dbg
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl-doc
```

I then tried:

```
pip install pycurl
```

I got:

```
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
  Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-de7mbdj3/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-85pj90gy --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: Using curl-config (libcurl 7.58.0)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
  copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
  running build_ext
  building 'pycurl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
  In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:0:
  src/pycurl.h:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
   #include <Python.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycurl
  Running setup.py clean for pycurl
Failed to build pycurl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-de7mbdj3/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0n2ynluk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Using curl-config (libcurl 7.58.0)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
    copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
    running build_ext
    building 'pycurl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
    In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:0:
    src/pycurl.h:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Python.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-de7mbdj3/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-0n2ynluk/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-de7mbdj3/pycurl/
```

After installing `libpython3.7-dev`:

```
Collecting pycurl
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e8/e4/0dbb8735407189f00b33d84122b9be52c790c7c3b25286826f4e1bdb7bde/pycurl-7.43.0.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
  Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ww9s3047/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-t5aeuzkr --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: Using curl-config (libcurl 7.58.0)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
  copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
  running build_ext
  building 'pycurl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easy.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easycb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easycb.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easyinfo.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyinfo.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easyopt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyopt.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easyperform.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyperform.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/module.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/multi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/multi.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/oscompat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/oscompat.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/pythoncompat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/pythoncompat.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/share.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/share.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/stringcompat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/stringcompat.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/threadsupport.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/threadsupport.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/util.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/util.o
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easycb.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyinfo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyopt.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyperform.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/module.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/multi.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/oscompat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/pythoncompat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/share.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/stringcompat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/threadsupport.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/util.o -lssl3 -lcurl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycurl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl3
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycurl
  Running setup.py clean for pycurl
Failed to build pycurl
Installing collected packages: pycurl
  Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ww9s3047/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-obgqqm_m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    ERROR: Using curl-config (libcurl 7.58.0)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
    copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
    running build_ext
    building 'pycurl' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easy.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easy.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easycb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easycb.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easyinfo.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyinfo.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easyopt.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyopt.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/easyperform.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyperform.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/module.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/module.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/multi.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/multi.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/oscompat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/oscompat.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/pythoncompat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/pythoncompat.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/share.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/share.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/stringcompat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/stringcompat.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/threadsupport.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/threadsupport.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.2" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_NSS=1 -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/util.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/util.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.7-0Cmdei/python3.7-3.7.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easy.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easycb.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyinfo.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyopt.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/easyperform.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/module.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/multi.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/oscompat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/pythoncompat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/share.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/stringcompat.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/threadsupport.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/util.o -lssl3 -lcurl -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/pycurl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl3
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ww9s3047/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-obgqqm_m/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-ww9s3047/pycurl/
```

Comment: Do you have `libpython3.7-dev` installed? `sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-devlibpython3.7-dev`

Comment: as you told I installed that I get different kind of error.

Comment: Now you also need `libssl3.so` and very likely the development files. `apt-get install libnss3 libnss3-dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some iterations it turned out that some development packages were missing to compile `pycurl`.

```
apt-get install libpython3.7-dev libnss3 libnss3-dev
```

---

The essential hint for `libpython3.7-dev` is as follows.

```
src/pycurl.h:4:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

This indicates that `Python.h` is missing or cannot be found. In this case it is a bit difficult to find the correlating package since a lot of packages provide this file. You can use

```
apt-file search Python.h
```

to search for packages that provide this file. Since you are trying to compile with the system provided Python 3.7 the package, it should also be named something like `libpython` including the version.

---

The second hint is as follows.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl3
```

This tells you that the linker cannot find the `libssl3.so` library to link the fresh compiled `pycurl` objects to. You can also use `apt-file search` to find packages providing this library. Not sure if the `-dev` package is also needed here, but it shouldn't matter if you just install it as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, and previous solutions did not work form me. And I had to change the path for openssl
I am commenting it here, I believe it might save someone's time.
Machine I am using

```
MacOS: Apple M1 Pro (Ventura v13.4)

pip uninstall pycurl
PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl
```